# getting data from mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb, sockets, collections, database

Trying to get some messages from a db collection, I've tried  that code (server side):

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/gt-chat', function(err, db) {
    if(err) throw err;
    var history="";
    var collection = db.collection('gt-chat');
    console.log("******************************Printing docs from Cursor Each")
    collection.find({}, {_id: 0}).sort({$natural: 1}).limit(20).each(function(err, doc) {
        console.log(doc)
        if(doc != null) {
            console.log("Doc from Each ");
            history=history+console.dir(doc)+"\r\n";
            console.dir(doc);
        }
    });

    console.log("/////////////HISTORY//////////////////");
    console.log(history); ; // data is shown there under the shell console, all is fine !

    socket.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER', history); // should send the messages using socket
});
```

and then on the client side, I've tried :

```
// listener, whenever the server emits 'updatechat', this updates the chat body
socket.on('updatechat', function (username, data) {
    date = new Date;
    h = date.getHours();
    if (h<10) {
        h = "0"+h;
    }
    m = date.getMinutes();
    if (m<10) {
        m = "0"+m;
    }
    s = date.getSeconds();
    if (s<10) {
        s = "0"+s;
    }
    var time = h+":"+m+":"+s;
    $('#conversation').append('<b><strong>' + time + '</strong>      '+username + ':</b> ' + data +     '<br>');
});
```

which doesn't show anything as expected :(
I am quite sure about the `updatechat` function because I can get message with it, as I've tried:

```
socket.emit('updatechat', 'SERVER',"this is history"); // < message is well sent, so no problem there!
```

but I don't get the all history. 
So the goal is to get some messages from a mongodb collection and to display them under the browser using socket emit

Under the shell, to debug, it's showing:

```
Doc from Each { message: '<strong>12:16:27</strong><span style=\'color:#2fed7e\'><b>guibs</b>< /span><em> hum</em>' } { message: '<strong>12:16:27</strong><span style=\'color:#2fed7e\'><b>guibs</b>< /span><em> hum</em>' }
```

So, data and messages exist, but I can't read them from the browser. The shell says: `'history is not defined'` ! What is wrong with concatenation? And my variable declaration? I don't understand, thanks for your help!